# cakephp error Table class for alias xxx could not be found

Tags: cakephp

This is my first time with cakephp (using xampp and phpmyadmin) and I just created table **orders** and controller for it in terminal using command: **.\cake bake controller orders**, but when i open it there is an error [error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gcvl.png). I tried with other names and tables but nothing worked. How do I fix it?

Comment: Can it be that its once __O__rders and once __o__rders ?   The error displays it with a capital first letter?

Comment: That's not it. Table name always changes to lowercase and since I tried making controllers multiple times, for sure I typed right. Now I checked and link works with capital first letter so it's propably just esthetical.

Comment: try `bin/cake bake model orders`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create model
run in terminal
./cake bake model orders